# Linux linking to any available library version

Tags: c++, c, linux, node.js, ubuntu

When compiling my binary (addon for node.js) on Ubuntu 13.10. then the linker takes libudev.so.1 to link.

Then I copy the binary to a Ubuntu 12.04 machine and run the binary. Then there is an error that libudev.so.1 can't be found. On Ubuntu 12.04 is libudev.so.0 installed.

I provide gcc with the param -ludev

The binary expects libudev.so.1. I checked it with this command:

```
$> strings bin | grep udev
$> ...
$> libudev.so.1
```

How can I tell the linker it should take any provided libudev version of the OS. So the binary would require something like `libudev.so*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the magical Linux world it is very difficult to compile and link on one machine and then copy the binary to another machine and run it there. There are a lot of variations, as you have also experienced not all aer compatible with each other, so this make the porting of binaries very difficult, if not altogether impossible. It might work with some setups, and not with others. Now you have two possibilities:

1. I assume, your 12.04 is a production environment so you cannot do whatever you want... So, in this case create an identical (virtual) machine to the Ubuntu 12.04 compile and link on it. Copy the executable to the 12.04 you need to run on it. Chances are that it will work without problems.
2. If the assumption about the production environment is not true, then install the compilers and necessary environment and compile the source on the remote machine. This way you will know it will work all the time on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

In your 12.04 find out at which location `libudev.so.0` is there. then make a symbolic link to that library with `libudev.so.1` and see.

To make symbolic link:

```
ln -sf /opt/lib/libudev.so.1   /opt/lib/libudev.so.0
```

Comment: Except that the major version change denotes that the binary API has changed in a (possibly) breaking way. If they were compatible, there'd normally already be a symlink there.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe yea if no API is changes then there should be symbolic link but if that is not there then just for try we can use this.